# Vswprintf returning -1

Tags: c++, ios, c

If anyone has an experience, what else other than null pointers that can cause vswprintf to return -1?

My situation is that when the vaarglist contains wchar that has big endian English chars, it runs fine. For example 0xa0000000.

But when it is in Japanese for example 0x582d0000 it will return -1.

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, but it could be a locale issue, wprintf and other wide char functions depend on it, you should check vswprintf_l or try setlocale

Comment: Can anyone expand on what Mux meant? Or any other ideas?

Comment: These functions are documented in `man` pages, e.g. in a shell you can run `man vswprintf` to see exactly how it works.  In this case it notes that it will fail if `n` or more wide characters were requested; so how exactly do you call `vswprintf()` (e.g. with what value of `n`)?

Comment: I don't get what they mean n or more?  I do input w_chars in from the arglist.  When inputting the above, English works but Japanese doesn't.  Do you think this is directly related to your "n or more wide character" finding?